# Cannot provide the Stream.iterate method with a method defined by me

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I am a fan of creating an easy to understand code. I also prefer to not repeat my code too often.
Today I am trying increase my functional programming skills in Java and I have encountered the problem below:

As the first step I am trying to generate a stream by using the Iterate() method. Everything is fine and the code at the bottom works when I am using:

```
Stream<Integer> numStream = Stream.iterate(0, x -> x +1);
```

However when I am trying to use a method defined by me.

```
Stream<Integer> numStream = Stream.iterate(0, Main::provideExpression);
```

My IDE is saying that: *The method iterate(T, UnaryOperator) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments(int, Main::provideExpression*

Could you please guys advise what I am doing wrong here ? thanks !

Full Code:

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stream<Integer> numStream = Stream.iterate(0, Main::provideExpression);
    List<Integer> squareNumbers = numStream.map(Main::power).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());

    printFormated(squareNumbers);

}

public static UnaryOperator<Integer> provideExpression() {
    return n -> n + 1;
}

public static <T> void printFormated(Collection<T> collection) {
    collection.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " ; "));
}

public static int power(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method reference does not evaluate to a unary operator. A unary operator does not return a unary operator. In your context, it should take and return an integer. It's its return type that is a unary operator.

I believe it will compile if you changed the second argument:

```
Stream<Integer> numStream = Stream.iterate(0, Main.provideExpression());
```

If you wanna use a method reference, then give it a unary operator's signature:

```
public static int provideExpression(int n) { 
    return  n + 1; 
}
```

A reference for this version of the method would be an int unary operator.

Comment: _A unary operator does not return a unary operator._ not true, as in some cases you may want a function that takes a _UnaryOperator_ and returns a _UnaryOperator_ which by definition is a _UnaryOperator_

Comment: Thank you so so much! I believe that based on that I have problems to understand the difference between invoking a method by a dot "." or by a double colon "::" Are you able please to explain that difference in a few words to me ? I would be really really grateful !

Comment: Also, note that `Main.provideExpression()` would not compile. when using method reference syntax you should not include a `.` nor the `()` at the end of the method name rather it should be `Main::provideExpression`

Comment: @Aominè Right, I intentionally generalized. We can all come up with a use case for unary operators to return unary operators, even if we know that it would simply be odious design. I needed to tie the thinking to the unary operations on integers.

Answer (score 0):

As is, your `provideExpression` function doesn’t respect the contract of the `UnaryOperator` as it doesn’t have a parameter and nor does it return the same type as it’s parameter (which the custom function currently doesn't have).

Rather, your custom function should be defined as:

```
public static int provideExpression(int input) {
       return input + 1;
}
```

because as the java doc states:

> [UnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) represents an operation on **a single operand that
>   produces a result of the same type as its operand**. This is a
>   specialization of Function for the case where the operand and result
>   are of the same type.